# Is there a way to apply CSS-transform to an element which is inside an element that is being CSS-transformed on mousemove?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Basically I have a parallax scene using [parallax.js](http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/) library.

Inside the scene I have a couple of divs with unique parallax settings data tags.
And inside one of these divs I have an element which I want apply tilt effect to(when its getting mouseover'ed). But it doesnt work, the transformations from tilt lib arent being applied if an element is inside the scene however it works if I move it out of the parallax scene.

I think the problem lies somewhere around the management of OnMouseMove events or maybe it cannot work that way(when transform is being applied to an already transformed element's child).

Chrome EventListeners tab shows that both parallax and tilt mousemove listeners exist.

I would appreciate any help. If you need any code snippets I can provide it, since right now I actually don't know what particular parts to show and dont want to copy paste the whole libs.

UPD.
here's a snippet of what im trying to do:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var scene = $('.prlx-scene').get(0);
  var parallaxInstance = new Parallax(scene, {
    relativeInput: true,
    invertX: false,
    invertY: false
  });
});
```

```css
.fulld,
.prlx-scene {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%
}

.prlx-scene {
  width: 80%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto
}

.fulld {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 12;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000fff;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover
}

.platonic-left-front-img {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

.platonic-left-front {
  z-index: 40;
}

.platonic-left-front-img {
  left: 20%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 40%
}

.pc-text1 {
  top: 50%;
  left: 10%;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 15%;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: #00ffff;
}

.pc-text {
  top: 50%;
  left: 30%;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 15%;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: #00ffff;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle
}

.scene-block {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parallax/3.1.0/parallax.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body style="height:100%;position:absolute;width:100%;">
  <div class="pc-text1" data-tilt data-tilt-max="40" data-tilt-speed="200" data-tilt-perspective="500" data-tilt-reverse="true" style="z-index:9999;transform-style: preserve-3d;">
    <p style="transform: translateZ(50px);">TEXT</p>
  </div>
  <div class="fulld">
    <div class="prlx-scene">
      <div class="scene-block" data-depth="0.8"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="platonic-left-front-img"></div>
      <div class="scene-block" data-depth="0.85">
        <div class="pc-text" data-tilt data-tilt-max="90" data-tilt-speed="400" data-tilt-perspective="500" data-tilt-reverse="true" style="transform-style: preserve-3d;">
          <p style="transform: translateZ(50px);">TEXT</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vanilla-tilt@1.6.1/lib/vanilla-tilt.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that parallax scene disables pointer events.

So in order for that to work I needed to add `style="pointer-events: all;"` to an element that is being tilted.